# .NET - Exception stack trace lines erased on generic methods

Tags: .net, winforms, generics, exception

(Initial content edited out because I discovered it was irrelevant)

My application has a general-purpose RESTful HTTP client which wraps operations in 
delegates and is past to my WrapOperation method (as seen below).

However, when exceptions are raised the stack trace only contains one entry:

```
at MyProject.Client.RestClient.WrapOperation[T](String method, String path, Object requestObject, RestOperation`1 action) in D:\{fileName}\RestClient.cs:line 196
```

I've reduced the problem code to just this:

```
private T WrapOperation<T>(String method, String path, Object requestObject, RestOperation<T> action) {

        HttpWebRequest request;
        RestTransaction txn = CreateRequest(method, path, requestObject, out request);

        ////////////////////////////

        try {

            throw new WebException("testing stack trace 6");
            throw new Exception("testing stack trace 7");

            using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {

                txn.GotResponse( response );

                return action( txn, response );
            }

        } catch(WebException wex) {
            // NOTE: When exceptions are caught, they're missing the first few entries of the stack trace
            // And appear as though "WrapOperation[T]" (sic) is the entrypoint. Why is this?


            if( wex.Response != null ) {

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wex.Response;

                txn.GotResponse( wex, response );

                CopyResponseToMemoryStream( response, txn ).Dispose();

            } else {

                txn.GotResponse( wex );
            }

            // NOTE: However, when these RestExceptions are caught (by WrapOperation's caller), their stack trace is complete and shows the entire trace
            throw new RestException("WebExeption during GetResponse.", txn, wex );

        } catch(Exception ex) {

            txn.GotResponse( ex );

            // NOTE: However, when these RestExceptions are caught (by WrapOperation's caller), their stack trace is complete and shows the entire trace
            throw new RestException("Non-WebException during GetResponse.", txn, ex );
        }

    }
```

When the "testing stack trace 6" exception is thrown, when caught by the catch(WebException wex), wex's stack trace only contains one entry.

Why is this?

Comment: What the exception code actually look like? Are you doing `throw ex` or just `throw` to pass the exception down the chain?

Comment: What method is the entry point for your threads? Is it <code>DoAsync(Action)</code>? Could you please show the code that creates, starts and executes the async tasks?

Comment: You didn't post the code of the missing intermediate methods so it is hard to guess.  At least two cases here afaict.  You'll only see the methods executed by the task, exception traces are thread-based.  And the jitter optimizer generates code for small methods inline so you can't see those, exceptions are stackframe based.  Use [MethodImpl] to suppress that optimization.

Comment: Sorry. I've completely rewritten the question after doing some research to narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your wrapping the original exception into a custom exception class. When you read the exception back out to look at the stack trace, your also going to have to examine the inner exception line to get the full trace back out.

edit -

The stack trace starts where the exception is thrown, so the stack trace shown is correct, and my original description of the problem is correct.

Anytime you throw a new exception the stack trace for that exception starts at that point.

In your original example again, examine the inner exception of here:

```
//throwing the exception resets the stack trace!
//the next catch will see the exception as coming from this line, and
//will need to look at the inner exception at that point to see the
//original exception! I Think! I have no idea what RestException is,
//only that your passing the original exception ex into it as a parameter.
throw new RestException("Non-WebException during GetResponse.", txn, ex );
```

Comment: The inner exception (as assigned when the RestExceptions are instantiated) has the initial stack frames missing - the fact I'm wrapping exceptions is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your (unshown) methods is catching the exception and then rethrowing it like so:

```
throw ex;
```

Then the stack trace will be reset to start at the rethrowing point.

```
throw;
```

Will maintain the stack trace.